# Obfuscate Phone Numbers Consistently

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, security

We have phone number fields that we need to obfuscate in a UAT environment, the problem is that the number needs to be unique, and should match other data processes using other databases that are also obfuscated. I'm trying to create a function that will reliably scramble a number, and each number passed in produces the same scrambled number every time, using some kind of encryption key that we'll store safely.   I haven't found a way to reliably reproduce numbers in the same 10 digit format.    Any ideas?

Comment: Why not hash them? Hashing won't allow you to "go back" to the original number, though. The benefit of hashing is you don't need a key.

Comment: Use fake data, or you could use a random number generator to produce 7 or 10 digit numbers.  Use the original number as the seed.   Usually time is used to created psuedo random numbers, but it sounds like in your case, it doesn't matter if the same number is created.

Comment: How certain do you need to be that there are no collisions?  The safest solution is to put the distinct phone numbers into a table and then assign a "random" number in the table.

Comment: Depending on your version of SQL Server you may also want to give `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` a look. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbypassphrase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Also, BINARY_CHECKSUM([PrimaryPhone])  seemed to work, but generated duplicates so it wasnt unique... there were more matches after running this than before..

Answer (score 0):

Why not use any hash function that will give you a guid?

E.g.

`hash('012345677899')`
in python

or
`SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', '0103203803')` in t-sql
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: `HASH` isn't a T-SQL function.

Comment: Note that if you go with hashing, the result depends on the input being byte-exact. That is, formating characters like dashes, parenthesis and the like need to match exactly. It may be convenient to "sanitize" them by leaving only numbers to hash.

Comment: This answer returns a `VARBINARY`, If you need a `VARCHAR`, you can do: `convert(int, hashbytes('SHA2_512', '012345677899'))` and then format it as needed.

Comment: Phone numbers in most countries are not all that large. It doesn't take a whole lot of computing power to run through all possible numbers, hash them, and compare them to stored hashes, so as a way of adding confidentiality against someone determined this is no good. Hashing is not encrypting, and in general encrypting small pieces of data both securely and efficiently is not an easy problem.

Comment: we tried the hash function, but it created negative numbers..   We're looking for a way to end up reliably with a 10 digit positive numeric value every time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Column Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data?view=sql-server-ver15) is what you're looking for. You can encrypt the column, then pass the encrypted value.

[SQLShack](https://www.sqlshack.com/an-overview-of-the-column-level-sql-server-encryption/) did a good write up as well.

Answer (score 0):

Column Encryption is not what Steve is looking for, the phone number fields needs to obfuscated in the lower environment after a refresh from production in 2 separate tables and guarantee the same number of rows match before and after the process completes.

The process below seems to have worked but the before count did not match the after count.

SET [somePhone] =  BINARY_CHECKSUM([somePhone])

Microsoft dynamic-data-masking may be a better option.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver15